# Voltage divider, no power

Tags: voltage, converter

I made a voltage divider using 2k4 and 4k7 resistors.

If I check the voltage with the multimeter, the voltage is correctly converted from 5V to 3.3V however when connect a consumer(small electric motor that should work with very low power) it does not work.

Why would this happen?

Comment: The current is limited by the resistors. Get a voltage regulator instead.

Comment: I don't think it's about the current, I used also a 5V 12A generator, still not working

Comment: The current that your motor draws is too much. So it **is** the current. By placing a motor (of for example 100 ohms) in parallel to the 4.7 k resistor you made a different voltage divider of 2.4 k ohm and (100 ohm in parallel with 4.7 kohm).

Answer (score 5):

You need a voltage regulator to drop 5 volt to 3.3 volts if you want to provide a decent enough current to drive an electric motor. A resistor divider will produce 3.3 volts open circuit but, as soon as you connect a load, you draw current and largely destroy the potential dividers ability to deliver a constant 3.3 volts.

Use a voltage regulator.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that a voltage divider made with simple resistor can not guarantee a fix voltage output if a load is apply. By adding this load, the resistance of the circuit change and then change the output :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fckSsp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$V_{out} = V_{in}*\frac{R_2 // R_{load}}{R_1+R_2//R_{load}}\$

As you can see, \$V_{out}\$ may change if you add a load.

As said @AndyAka, you remplace the voltage divider by a voltage regulator. It's extremely easy to use (few resistor and capacitor) and it will fit your need.